# merge duplicate rows in columns

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, perl

Given a file like this:

```
x y y z x
x x y z z y
x x x z y
y z z y x x x
x x x x x
```

I would like the output to be:

```
x y+ z x
x+ y z+ y
x+ z y
y z+ y x+
x+
```

Is that possible to do with awk or perl in a oneliner? i.e. is it possible to find any number of similar values in rows and merge them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `perl` version can also deal with arbitrary field lengths, not only those of a single character:

```
$ perl -lpae 'for $i (@F){s/($i\s*){2,}/$i+ /g}' file 
x y+ z x
x+ y z+ y
x+ z y
y z+ y x+ 
x+
```

On a more complex file:

```
$ cat file
foo foo foo bar foo
bar foo bar bar foo
foo foo x x x bar
$ perl -lpae 'for $i (@F){s/($i\s*){2,}/$i+ /g}' file 
foo+ bar foo
bar foo bar+ foo
foo+ x+ bar
```

#### Explanation

The `-l` trims newlines from each input line, the `-a` splits input fields on whitespace into the array `@F` and the `-p` prints each input line after applying the script given by `-e`.

The script itself iterates over each input field (the `@F` array), saving each as `$i`. The substitution looks for 2 or more consecutive `$i` followed by 0  or more spaces and replaces them with `$i+`.

Answer (score 6):

```
sed 's/\(.\)\( \1\)\{1,\}/\1+/g' <in >out
```

---

```
x y+ z x
x+ y z+ y
x+ z y
y z+ y x+
x+
```

With BSD or GNU `sed`:

```
sed -Ee's/(.)( \1)+/\1+/g' <in >out
```

To work with arbitrary field lengths, you just do it with arbitrary field lengths:

```
sed -Ee 's/(...)( \1)+/\1+/g' <<""
xxx yyy yyy zzz xxx
xxx xxx yyy zzz zzz yyy
xxx xxx xxx zzz yyy
yyy zzz zzz yyy xxx xxx xxx
xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
```

---

```
xxx yyy+ zzz xxx
xxx+ yyy zzz+ yyy
xxx+ zzz yyy
yyy zzz+ yyy xxx+
xxx+
```

Or w/ @terdon's input slightly modified in the second line:

```
sed -Ee's/(([^ ]+ *)+)( +\1)+/<\1>+/g' <<""
foo foo foo bar foo
bar foo bar foo
foo foo x x x bar
```

---

```
<foo>+ bar foo
<bar foo>+
<foo>+ <x>+ bar
```